# How can I stop gedit crashing when using save as?

Tags: virtualbox, gedit

I keep encountering a problem when trying to use the <kbd>Save As</kbd> functionality in gedit when I am running a model that keeps creating files in the directory I am looking at.

I have opened a file and edited it I then wish to save the file under a different name. I go to <kbd>File</kbd> then <kbd>Save As</kbd>. As gedit tries to open the (window?) from which I should be able to save the file, it is unable to complete its search for files in the directory as files continue to appear. Basically it looks like gedit is trying to discover all of the files in the directory but can't as the list keeps getting longer (due to output from a model I am running).

Gedit then becomes unresponsive. Is there a way to stop this from happening, such as perhaps stopping gedit from trying to find all the files in the directory? Can I do this from the command line?

I am using 12.04 as guest in VirtualBox with Windows 8.1 as the host.

Comment: I am afraid you have to explain a bit more about what you are trying to let gedit do, and by what mechanism.

Comment: Is this any better?

Comment: what I don't understand is: 1) why (and initiated by what) is gedit trying to discover too many files. 2) The edits you make, are they necessarily done manually or can it be done by a script? It seems you are running a process that runs faster than that its result is processed (by you?). That is what (as I understand) is causing the "infarct" (again, if I understand well). Can you simply explain what the goal is of the whole setup, and how it is organized?

Comment: I am trying to use save as in gedit in a directory which is having files added to it. The two tasks are not connected directly. Basically I am trying to set up a different model run while the model is running. I am not editing any of the files the model is using but I am in the same directory that the model outputs to.